# .gitignore file does not seem to work and still shows the Xcode files

Tags: swift, xcode, git, github, gitignore

My app uses a NASA API to get images from the mars rover. The file where I keep the api key is called Constrant.swift. I tried to hide this file by creating a .gitingore file. I typed Constrant.swift into the .gitignore file and then pressed save and pushed all of the files to GitHub. The problem that I am having is that when I pushed all of the files the Constrant.swift was all pushed and was not ignored. The api key is not that important, but I would still like to know what I did wrong and how to fix it.

The link to the repository is [here](https://github.com/Stanley-Moukhametzianov/Swiftui-NASA-Mars-Rover-Images-App). As you can see the .gitignore file is still there and has Constrant.swift. However, when you press nasaAPI, the Constrant.swift file is still there. Also I created the .gitignore file before I added the Constrant.swift file. How would I remove this file from GitHub and hide it in the .gitignore file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you must also add the folder in where the *Constrant.swift* is located to `.gitignore`, and not only the file name:

```
nasaAPI/Constrant.swift
```

Then if the file is already tracked (pushed on remote repository on a previous commit), you must *untrack* this file with following command:

```
git rm --cache nasaAPU/Constrant.swift
```

An other way to ignore this file is to write *two* stars in front of it. Then you ignore every file with the name *Constrant.swift* in that repository. So you doesn‘t need to add the folder name where *Constrant.swift* is located before. But be careful with that:

```
**/Constrant.swift
```

After that, you can add (`git add .`) your changes (edited `.gitignore` and untrack the *Constrant.swift* file) and commit (`git commit -m "No longer tracking Constrant.swift to include in gitignore"`) them.

Now, after `git push`, *Constrant.swift* isn‘t longer available on the GitHub remote repository.